# Check private class methods call order

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

**Hello!**

> **Tl;dr**: I need to check that public class method calls private class methods in specific order depending on some condition. How can I do this?

Considering having such class:

```
class SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self, param: ParamsEnum):
        self._param = param

    def process(self):
        if self._param == ParamsEnum.VALUE_1:
            self._do_intermediate_process()
        self._do_process()

    def _do_process(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def _do_intermediate_process(self):
        pass
```

I want to write a unit test to check that process logic. I tried few approaches but none of them was succeeded.

**Approach one** - using separate Mock() as container.

```
@mock.patch.object(SomeClass, '_do_process')
@mock.patch.object(SomeClass, '_do_intermediate_process')
def test_process(self, mocked_do_process, mocked_do_intermediate_process):
    mock_container = Mock()
    mock_container.m0, mock_container.m1 = mocked_do_process, mocked_do_intermediate_process

    instance = SomeClass(ParamsEnum.VALUE_1)
    instance.process()

    mocked_do_process.assert_called_once()
    mocked_do_intermediate_process.assert_called_once()
    mock_container.assert_has_calls([mock_container.m0, mock_container.m1])
```

As a result, `mock_container.method_calls` shows nothing.

**Approach two** - mocking 'process' with keeping original logic as side effect. This test is passing regardless of mocked method order on the last line.

```
@mock.patch.object(SomeClass, '_do_process')
@mock.patch.object(SomeClass, '_do_intermediate_process')
def test_process(self, mocked_do_process, mocked_do_intermediate_process):
    origignal_process = SomeClass.process
    with mock.patch.object(SomeClass, 'process', autospec=True) as mocked_process:
        def side_effect(self):
            return origignal_process(self)
        mocked_process.side_effect = side_effect

        class_mock = Mock(spec=SomeClass, autospec=True)
        class_mock.process = mocked_process
        class_mock._do_process = mocked_do_process
        class_mock._do_intermediate_process = mocked_do_intermediate_process
        class_mock._param = ParamsEnum.VALUE_1

        class_mock.process(class_mock)

        mocked_do_process.assert_called_once()
        mocked_do_intermediate_process.assert_called_once()
        mocked_process.assert_called_once()
        class_mock.assert_has_calls([mocked_do_intermediate_process, mocked_do_process])
```

Answer (score 0):

One mistake first:

```
@mock.patch.object(SomeClass, '_do_process')
@mock.patch.object(SomeClass, '_do_intermediate_process')
def test_process(self, mocked_do_process, mocked_do_intermediate_process):
```

should really be:

```
@mock.patch.object(SomeClass, '_do_process')
@mock.patch.object(SomeClass, '_do_intermediate_process')
def test_process(self, mocked_do_intermediate_process, mocked_do_process):
```

The order does matter a lot.

https://thadeusb.com/weblog/2010/08/23/python_multiple_decorators/

> When you stack multiple decorators onto a python function, there is an order that these decorators will get executed in, which is not mentioned in the documentation.

The decorators are executed from innermost to outermost. For example.
Select

```
@i_get_called_last
@i_get_called_second
@i_get_called_first
def my_decorated_function():
    return 1+2
```

So when designing your decorators, make sure that the first and second called decorators return compatible functions that the decorators preceding it would be able to operate with.

> using ***separate*** Mock() as container.

It simply will not work by creating a Mock object, it has to be called with `mock_container.method()` to create and call the method.

```
mock_container = mock.Mock()
>>>mock_container.called
False
>>> mock_container()
<Mock name='mock()' id='140078609813744'>
>>> mock_container.called
True
>>> mock_container.ma()
<Mock name='mock.ma()' id='140078608707880'>
>>> mock_container.ma.called
True
```